# Why can't a method in the instance of my javascript class see a property

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

A property set in the constructor of a class is not available to other functions in that instance of the class

The class constructor takes an object as data as its argument. This is then saved as a property of the instance - all good.

```
const form = new Form({
  "name": "John",
  "description": "a good bloke",
  "box_id": 1
});
```

I can see that `form.orginalData` is the object passed however when I run

```
form.toString()
```

I get an empty object (set in the function called data)

Here is the example in full

```js
class Form {
  constructor(data) {
    this.orginalData = data
    for (let field in this.orginalData) {
      this[field] = data[field];
    }

  }
  data() {
    let d = {};
    for (let p in this.originalData) {
      d[p] = this[p];
    }

    return d;
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.data());
  }

}
const form = new Form({
  "name": "John",
  "description": "a good bloke",
  "box_id": 1
});
let message = document.getElementById('message');

form.name = 'Ian';
form.description = 'is a wicked man';

message.innerHTML = form.name + '<br/>';
message.innerHTML += form.description + '<br/>';
message.innerHTML += "orginalData:" + JSON.stringify(form.orginalData) + '<br/>'
message.innerHTML += "<p>BUT if I run form.data() I get </p>"
message.innerHTML += form.toString();
```

```css
#message {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Class property persistance
</h1>
<p>
  output:
</p>
<div id="message">
  Something went wrong
</div>
```

I am obviously missing something fairly fundamental

Comment: `this[p]` should be `this.originalData[p]`.

Comment: You an also replace the loop with `let d = Object.assign({}, this.originalData);`

Comment: You have a typo: `this.orginalData` should be `this.originalData`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting empty result because originalData vs orginalData

Comment: Oh my word - large face palm. The perils of mild dyslexia. Thanks to all who looked at this.